# How to detect temporality of a sentence in R

Tags: r

I have a series of sentences in R and I would like to figure out whether they are in the past or future tense

eg:

```
She has already started her medication                 PAST
A better option would be for her to start this stuff   FUTURE
She has been prescribed 35mg of things.                PAST
```

Is this achievable with POS tagging/ is there a simpler way?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139866/finding-tense-of-a-sentence-using-stanford-nlp#22146151) help?

Comment: @Aramis7d is the Pennbank implemented in R or will other POS taggers also give me verb tenses?